# Нужна помощь с условиями проверки

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я еще плохо разбираюсь в sql, но нужна помощь с написанием условия.
Мне нужно, чтобы, когда пользоватесь нажимает на старт в телеграм боте, его id и имя записывалось в бд. Это я сделал, но если этот же пользователь снова нажимает старт, то строчка с его данными дублируется, и я хочу сделать проверку, если такой id уже есть в бд, то не добавлять ничего, если нет, то добавляет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(один из моих неправильных вариантов)

Может кто помочь написать данную проверку ?

Comment: Для исключения создания дублирующихся записей в таблице создают уникальный индекс. Попытка вставить дубликат приведёт к ошибке нарушения уникальности, запись не вставится.

Comment: Ну в любом случае, почему тут ошибку показывает ?

Comment: Потому что каждое предложение в хранимом объекте должно терминироваться. А в показанном коде INSERT не терминирован.